QGIS using selectedLayer.getFeatures() but require str for ComboBox
I have written a QGIS plugin to pull features from a layer and then perform various calculations.
The code successfully extracts the full dataset, but I want to populate a ComboBox to be able to select a given row from the data set.
    def select_line(self):
    """Load lines from chosen layer and populate LineCB."""
    global selectedLayer
    selectedLayer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
    self.dlg.LineCB.clear()
    L_names = []
    # get the names and add to the list
    for x in selectedLayer.getFeatures():
        L_names.append(x['Seq'])
    self.dlg.LineCB.addItems(L_names)  # Populate the ComboBox
    self.dlg.LineCB.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.get_coords)

The column of data labelled 'Seq' can contain Integers or '-'.
If 'Seq' contain only integers, I get the following QGIS Python error.
         self.dlg.LineCB.addItems(L_names) # Populate the ComboBox
         TypeError: index 0 has type 'int' but 'str' is expected

If I print(L_names) I can see that they are all read as text if '-' is present in the data, but as integers if only numbers are present.
Is there a way to either force L_names to default to Str, convert them or get the ComboBox to accept Int?  I can use Name instead of Seq, which dodges the problem as they are always alphanumeric, but it's easier to work with Seq.
    Name    ID  Seq Heading
EQ24322-01001-04    1   -   1.287
EQ24322-01005-08    2   -   1.287
EQ24322-01009-12    3   -   1.287
EQ24322-01013-16    4   -   1.287
EQ24322-01017-20    5   29  181.287
EQ24322-01021-24    6   27  181.287
EQ24322-01025-28    7   25  181.287


Use an f-string: L_names.append(f”{x[‘seq’]}”)

Thankyou @couteau, that solved the problem.
